# Is it possible to use the same disk data both for table and index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, storage

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  table_a_id integer NOT NULL,
  table_b_id integer NOT NULL,
  table_c_id integer NOT NULL,
  data numeric(30, 0) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table (table_a_id, table_b_id, table_c_id);
```

As per my knowledge it seems I'm doubling the disk space as each index row has a copy of three fields from the table `(table_a_id, table_b_id, table_c_id)` plus the "item identifier" pointing to the table row.
This means each query has to read data from the disk twice.

Is there a way (**in PostgreSQL**) to create a table with only one index using the same disk space for both?

Comment: You can only determine what indexes you need if you know the queries.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no way in Postgres** to (re-)use the same data from storage for table (the main relation, the "heap") and index. Each is stored separately.

**But** that does not necessarily mean that ...

> each query has to read data from the disk twice.

[Index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) are possible if the index includes all columns needed to satisfy the query.

An index is typically only useful (and actually used) if no more than a few percent of all table rows have to be read. (While without index you'd have to read all.)

And an index is typically (much) smaller than the main relation. For starters, the index tuple header only occupies 8 bytes vs. 24 for a table row. You typically have only one or a few columns in an index, and Postgres 13 or later can [compress duplicative index entries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION). Related:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43142/3684)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Comment: So (to be concise) are you suggesting me create the index with all the columns of the table? If I understood correctly this will reduce the amount of data read from disk while quering the table.

Comment: @DanieleRicci: The best indexing strategy depends on the whole situation. Indexes should be as small as possible and as big as necessary. Indexing is complex. There are various index types, access methods, etc.